# Why does reducing with concatination give a scalar in APL?

Tags: arrays, scalar, apl

Note that I'm using Dyalog APL for the following.

Given:

```
      S←'string'
      S
string
      ⍴S
6
      ⍴⍴S
1
      DISPLAY S
┌→─────┐
│string│
└──────┘
```

If I perform a reduction with concatenation, I get a scalar:

```
      S_←,/S
      S_
 string 
      ⍴S_

      ⍴⍴S_
0
      DISPLAY S_
┌──────────┐
│ ┌→─────┐ │
│ │string│ │
│ └──────┘ │
└∊─────────┘
```

Naturally, I can no longer access the elements of my "array". I was wondering why this behavior occurs? I had believed that `/` acted like `foldr` and that `,` produced a vector, so why do I end up with a scalar result at the end?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you figured out that you can get to yout vector with `⊃S_` - it has been nested.

If you look at the doc of reduction in Dyalog's help, it reads:

```
R is an array formed by applying function f between items of the vectors 
along the Kth (or implied) axis of Y.

For a typical vector Y, the result is:

⊂(1⊃y)f(2⊃y)f......f(n⊃y)
```

Notice the ⊂ (enclose) at the beginning! The result is nested - which might be a bit confusing, because you do not experience that with a `+/`.
However, when you look at `+/⍳5`, this evolves to `⊂1+2+3+4+5` which returns scalar 15 - nesting a scalar does not affect its depth.
It's different with '`,`', because that operation returns an object with a different 'sizing-policy': catenating two scalars creates a vector with two elements. So, as promised, your `S_` is a string-vector with 6 elements that has been nested (see definition above).

Comment: "you can get to yout vector with `1⊃S_`"  You mean `⊃S_`

Comment: Yes. And `{disclose}S` (sorry, iphone doesnt have APL yet) is `[]ML`-dependent! ;-)

Comment: Not when applied to a one-element vector.